# Find $g:\mathbb{R}^m\to V$ such that $g(x)\notin\mathrm{span}\{f_1(x),\ldots,f_k(x)\}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional real vector space and let
$$f_1,\ldots,f_k:\mathbb{R}^m\to V$$
be $k<n$ smooth functions. It is intuitively obvious that we can always find a smooth function $g:\mathbb{R}^m\to V$ such that 
$$g(x)\notin\mathrm{span}\{f_1(x),\ldots,f_k(x)\}$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$.

Yet, I can't find a way to prove it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you need $g(x)$ to be smooth? If not, this is trivial...

Comment: @N.S. Yes, $g$ needs to be smooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample: Take $m= 2, V=\mathbb R^2, k=1.$ Define $f_1(x,y) = (x,y).$ Suppose there is such a $g$ in this situation. Then $g$ can never vanish. In particular, $g(0,0)\ne (0,0).$

So now think about it: In a small neighborhood of $(0,0),$ $g\approx g(0,0),$ a nonzero vector. So $g$ has nearly constant direction in this neighborhood. On the other hand, $f_1$ takes on every direction in every deleted neighborhood of $(0,0).$ It follows that $f_1(x,y),g(x,y)$ will be parallel* somewhere in such a neighborhood (in fact at lots of points). At any such point, we have $g(x,y)$ in the span of $f_1(x,y).$

*You can prove this rigorously by using the cross product, noting that it is positive for some $(x,y)\ne (0,0),$ negative for other $(x,y)\ne (0,0),$ and invoking the intermediate value theorem to see it is $0$ for some $(x,y)\ne (0,0).$